# Unexpected variable update when using bash's $(( )) operator for arithmetic

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to trim a few lines from a file. I know exactly how many lines to remove (say, 2 from the top), but not how many total lines are in the file. So I tried this straightforward solution:

```
$ wc -l $FILENAME
119559 my_filename.txt
$ LINES=$(wc -l $FILENAME | awk '{print $1}')
$ tail -n $(($LINES - 2)) $FILENAME > $OUTPUT_FILE
```

The output is fine, but what happened to LINES??

```
$ wc -l $OUTPUT_FILE
119557 my_output_file.txt
$ echo $LINES
107
```

Hoping someone can help me understand what's going on.

Comment: I cannot tell you what's happening with LINES, but I can offer an alternate solution: head(1)/tail(1) allow skipping the N first/last lines, so you don't have to do any math yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$LINES` has a special meaning. It is the number of rows the terminal has, and if you resize your terminal window, it will be re-set. See `info "(bash)Bash Variables"`.

Comment: This is just another reason you you should never use all-caps variable names: to avoid collision with environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to decompose where you thing the problem is. Running

```
 wc -l $FILENAME | awk '{print $1}'
```

should probably show you where the problem is.

Instead, use

```
LINES=$(wc -l < $FILENAME )
```

Hm.. Yes, I'm afraid @MichaelHoffman is probably has diagnosed your problem more accurately.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do `sed 'X,Yd' < file`

Where X,Y is the range of the lines you want to omit (in this case it would be 1,2).

Other alternatives are:

`sed 'X,+Yd'` omits Y lines starting from line X

`sed /regex/,Yd'` omits everything between the line where the regex matches and Y

`sed '/regex/,+Yd'` omits Y lines starting from where the regex matches

`sed '/regex/,/regex/d'` omits everything between the two regexs

**Note:** these are GNU sed extensions